# How to find the line number in XML string whern element value is provided?

Tags: java, xml

I want to get the line nimber from the dynamix XML string when the node value is passed. For example, if I give the input as "RSS Tutorial" the output should return the line number as 9. How to achieve this in java?

The sample XML is given below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0">

<channel>
  <title>W3Schools Home Page</title>
  <link>http://www.w3schools.com</link>
  <description>Free web building tutorials</description>
  <item>
    <title>RSS Tutorial</title>
    <link>http://www.w3schools.com/rss</link>
    <description>New RSS tutorial on W3Schools</description>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>XML Tutorial</title>
    <link>http://www.w3schools.com/xml</link>
    <description>New XML tutorial on W3Schools</description>
  </item>
</channel>

</rss>
```

Answer (score 1):

This [blog post](http://eyalsch.wordpress.com/2010/11/30/xml-dom-2/) presents a valid approach using SAX, using a [Locator](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/Locator.html).

Comment: Link only answers are generally discouraged. Try to add a small example in code or a brief description of the content of the blog in your answer.

Comment: @Rudi I dont't want to plagiarize someone else's post, and I think by saying that the approach is based on a Locator, I've provided more than a link-only answer.